# Calculating satellite position in lat, lon given the position of receiver, altitude of satellite, azimuth and elevation angles

Tags: gps, satellite, position

I want to calculate position of a satellite, given the position of the receiver, azimuth,elevation angles and height above ellipsoid for the satellite. I think this should be a simple geometry problem but I am confused by the considerations for Earth's shape etc. I wonder if there is an easy walk through to do this?